# Pegar valor de um button radio

Tags: javascript

Como eu faria para pegar os valores do radio button? Tentei com o código abaixo, mas só me retorna o valor do primeiro:

```
<input type='radio' name='Seguro' id="seguro" onchange="soma()" value='Sim'> Sim
<input type='radio' name='Seguro' id"seguro" onchange="soma()" value='Não'> Não
```

E o javascript ( teste ):

```
function soma(){

....
alert(document.getElementById("seguro").value);
....

}
```

Comment: da uma olhada nisso, quem sabe não te ajuda
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604167/how-can-we-access-the-value-of-a-radio-button-using-the-dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode utilizar essa solução que está no [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17422390/get-only-checked-element-from-getelementsbyname-in-javascript) inglês.

```
var choices = [];
var els = document.getElementsByName('choice_shrd_with_me');
for (var i=0;i<els.length;i++){
  if ( els[i].checked ) {
    choices.push(els[i].value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No seu caso os dois inputs estão com o mesmo id, você pode alterar o id, ou passar o próprio elemento como parâmetro da função assim = `onchange="soma(this)";` e depois alterar seu js para receber o parâmetro.

Answer (score 0):

Olá

tente ao invés de:

```
alert(document.getElementById("seguro").value);
```

utilizar:

```
var seg = document.querySelector('input[name=seguro]:checked').value
alert(seg)
```

ou até:

```
alert(document.querySelector('input[name=seguro]:checked').value)
```

Espero ajudar alguém, mesmo depois de tanto tempo, pois eu mesmo fui ajudado.