# Pegar o valor de um input radio com JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="radio" name="opcao" id="1" value="op1">
<input type="radio" name="opcao" id="2" value="op2">
<input type="radio" name="opcao" id="3" value="op4">
<input type="radio" name="opcao" id="4" value="op8">
```

Como pego o valor de cada opção e utilizo em uma função JavaScript a partir de um `onclick`?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Pegar valores checkbox com javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/83463/pegar-valores-checkbox-com-javascript)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Pegar valor de um button radio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82968/pegar-valor-de-um-button-radio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar um evento `onclick` para cada `radio` e enviar o valor para uma outra função:

```js
// aqui eu crio uma coleção de todos os input do tipo radio
// o seletor "input[type='radio']" é: nome_da_tag[atributo=valor]
var radios = document.body.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']");

// faço um loop na coleção começando do índice 0 até o limite da
// coleção (quantidade - 1). Por isso o x só deve ser menor do que
// a quantidade de itens na coleção
for(var x=0; x<radios.length; x++){

   // crio um evento onclick individual para cada elemento
   radios[x].onclick = function(){
   
      // this.value => o "this" é o elemento clicado
      // e "value" o valor dele. Envio para a função "clique()"
      // o valor em forma de parâmetro
      clique(this.value);
   }
}

// função que vai receber o valor do radio clicado
// em forma de um parâmetro que chamei de "i"
function clique(i){
   console.log(i);
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="opcao" id="1" value="op1">
<input type="radio" name="opcao" id="2" value="op2">
<input type="radio" name="opcao" id="3" value="op4">
<input type="radio" name="opcao" id="4" value="op8">
```

Comment: tem como salvar o this.value em uma variável?  para q eu possa comparar com outro  valor?

Comment: Tem sim, basta fazer `var variavel = this.value;`

Comment: Ou na função `clique()`: `var variavel = i;`

Comment: Tem muito material na internet. Melhor pra aprender é ir criado dúvidas e buscando respostas.

Comment: Vou adicionar comentários no código pra facilitar o entendimento e o que cada coisa faz.